# MVC4 - Uploading Image - Generic GDI+ Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, file-upload, gdi

I'm trying to upload an image and when I try image.Save(), I get a "generic GDI+" error. Any help would be great.

```
    // This action handles the form POST and the upload
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file, string filename)
    {
        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {                
            string location = "~/Content/Images/Specials/" + "rttest" + ".jpg";
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file.InputStream);
            Image image = (Image)bitmap;
            image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            image.Save(location);            
        }
        // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The location of "~/Content/Images/Specials/..." is inaccessible by GDI+ because it isn't a physical path. You need to use `Server.MapPath()` to map the virtual path to a physical path.

```
 string location = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Specials/" + "rttest" + ".jpg");
```

Also, it's weird that you're concatenating part of the path, then "rrest" then ".jpg". May want to look into that before putting it into production so you aren't overwriting your images over and over.